# UTC time stamp format - Split in parts a string containing the UTC time date (classic asp/vbscript)

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I believe that my question is misunderstood:

My string `(uuttcc)` contains a **UTC time stamp format**, created in other page with JAVASCRIPT.

I want to point out again, that my string contain exactly this: **Wed, 10 Jan 2018 17:23:34 UTC**

Is there any way to break apart this--> (`Wed, 10 Jan 2018 17:23:34 UTC`) to that--> (`YYYY/MM/DD`) ?

---

I have a string (`uuttcc`) that contains the UTC date / time.

The:

```
<%
Response.Write(uuttcc)
%>
```

Giving me the following result:

*Wed, 10 Jan 2018 17:23:34 UTC*

Is there any particular way to split this string in 3 parts like `DD YY MM` in classic ASP/VBScript??

Comment: `Datepart` ????

Comment: @ Lankymart, Is there any particular reason that all of you blocked my question as duplicate???
Your reference to the similar (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22574092/format-current-date-and-time) answered question it has nothing to do with my question.
 My question was very clean and simple:
I am trying to split this Wed, 10 Jan 2018 17:23:34 UTC exactly as is written
And not the ''now'' that you answered in the reference article.

Comment: @lankymart They missed it's a string parsing problem, not a date problem, as it appears on a quick read (as did I the first time I read it). Use `Arr()=Split(Str," ")` and access each element in the array. And you can do it more than once if you say want the seconds.

Comment: @ACatInLove - Thank very much for your attention! Can you please help me a little bit more… The name of my string  is ‘’uuttcc’’ and no, I don’t need seconds

Comment: You cannot program without Help. Download here http://download.microsoft.com/download/winscript56/Install/5.6/W982KMeXP/EN-US/scrdoc56en.exe and search for the `Split` function. So first line. `Dim MyArr=Split(uuttcc, " ")` To print out the day and keeping the comma. `Msgbox MyArr(0)`.

Comment: @ACatInLove I didn't miss nothing, its got nothing to do with parsing a string if they use `CDate()` to parse the string as a date then pull out the various date parts using in built functions. But then you'd know that if you used VBScript.

Comment: @user2986570 let me put it this way... You think you're the first person who has asked how to parse a string as a date in the years people have been asking questions on [so] about VBScript? It's VBScript 101 go back read [ask] and you will find the answer. You don't even need `Split()` in this instance and even if you did, it's not difficult and there are plenty of questions about splitting and parsing date strings. You've heard of `CDate()` right?

Comment: @ACatInLove you know `Dim variable=something` isn't valid VBScript syntax. Did you read the program help?

Comment: @Lankymart I am not a programmer. I am mainly web designer with very few knowledge in ASP/Vbscrip. Regarding you and all the others programmers in stackoverflow I am nothing. Of course I do not try to compare your knowledge to mine, because I do not have that kind of knowledge at all.
My problem is that my question was very clean and you blocked it.
I don’t ask to break in parts the “”now”” function (like the already answered question that you say that is similar to mines. I was very specific that I was trying to break apart my string Wed, 10 Jan 2018 17:23:34 UTC. Thank you.

Comment: @user2986570 your knowledge of the topic is not the issue. It's your ability to search existing questions and find your answer that is.

Comment: @Lankymart `CDate` does not recognise that string, with or without the trailing UTC.

Comment: @ACatInLove even with `SetLocale` set? I’m not near a computer to test it but regardless this isn’t the first time this has been asked, they just need to put some effort in. Even a [mcve] would be enough. So far it’s just, I have this and want this...give me the code.

Comment: @Lankymart The duplicate is WRONG answer to this specific question. To my knowledge no locales does dates backwards. Despite him talking about dates it is really just a string parsing problem. Date is a red herring.

Comment: @ACatInLove in which case go and find a string parsing question and suggest that as the duplicate. Regardless it has been and will be asked again.

Comment: I don't know how to do that. And I can't find any parsing answers that fit here.

Comment: @ACatInLove Finally I have found the way to separate in different parts that UTC timestamp, with arrays as you initially proposed by you. Thank you.

Comment: @Lankymart I am not asking for a ready (copy paste) code. I just asked to suggest me a way. Unfortunately the CDATE that you propose cannot read the string (even without the UTC characters in the end. Next time try not naming a question as duplicate without any reason.

Comment: More examples of date strings - [Converting Time-Stamp String to Another Date Format in VBScript](//stackoverflow.com/q/33279052)

Comment: @user2986570 have [updated my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22575530/692942) if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wasn't going to answer but with all the fluff in the comments, use `Split()`.

```vb
Dim input: input = "Wed, 10 Jan 2018 17:23:34 UTC"
Dim parsed: parsed = ParseDateString(input)
Dim output: output = Year(parsed) & "/" & Right("00" & Month(parsed), 2) & "/" & Right("00" & Day(parsed), 2)
Call Response.Write(output)

Function ParseDateString(value)
    'Split the string into manageable chunks.
    Dim parts: parts = Split(value, Chr(32))
    Dim dt, tm
    'Check the split created an array we can work with.
    If IsArray(parts) Then
        'Ignore the first element and use elements 1 - 3 to 
        'create the date structure.
        dt = parts(1) & Chr(32) & parts(2) & Chr(32) & parts(3)
        'Use the 5th element for the time structure.
        tm = parts(4)
        'Stitch them together to form a date variable.
        dt = CDate(dt & Chr(32) & tm)
    Else
        'We don't have a valid format return an empty string.
        dt = Empty
    End If
    ParseDateString = dt
End Function
```

Output:

```
2018/01/10
```

#### What about not using `Split()`?

The main issue is getting the string to be recognised by `CDate()` once you have this using [inbuilt date functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22575530/692942) will allow you to build whatever format you want.

In fact the only thing that breaks that particular parse using `CDate()` is the `Wed,` and `UTC`, so you ignore them using a combination of `Mid()`, `InStr()` and `Len()` as in this compact example;

```vb
Dim input: input = "Wed, 10 Jan 2018 17:23:34 UTC"
Dim output: output = CDate(Mid(input, InStr(1, input, ",") + 1, ((Len(input) - 4) - InStr(1, input, ","))))
'You now have a valid `Date` variable you can manipulate to your hearts
'content.
Call Response.Write(output)
```

```
10/01/2018 17:23:34
```

---

### Useful Links

- [How to convert string to datetime format classic asp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710309/how-to-convert-string-to-datetime-format-classic-asp)
- [Does VBScript have a DateTime.TryParse equivalent?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2517306/692942)
- [date format in VBS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9641000/692942)
- [Format current date and time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22575530/692942)

Comment: It was completely impossible for me and my poor knowledge to manage to write so complete and professional syntax of code. I apologize for the inconvenience maybe caused by my question.

Answer (score 0):

Use Split() to get the parts of your input string. Feed the correct parts to DateSerial()/CDate() to get a **Date** that should display/print as /d/m/y if that's the way of your locale/Regional settings. If you don't need a Date, build the desired `String` via Join(). As in:

```
Option Explicit

Function mkDicMonth()
  Dim dicT :  Set dicT = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  Dim i 
  For i = 1 To 12
      dicT(MonthName(i, True)) = i 
  Next
  Set mkDicMonth = dicT
End Function

Dim sInp   : sInp = "Wed, 10 Jan 2018 17:23:34 UTC"
Dim dicM   : Set dicM = mkDicMonth()
Dim aParts : aParts = Split(sInp)
Dim sOtp   : sOtp = Join(Array(aParts(1), dicM(aParts(2)), aParts(3)), "/")
WScript.Echo TypeName(sOtp), sOtp

Dim dtOtp
' DateSerial
dtOtp = DateSerial(CInt(aParts(3)), CInt(dicM(aParts(2))), CInt(aParts(1)))
WScript.Echo 1, TypeName(dtOtp), dtOtp, "(german locale, dmy)"

' CDate (risky, order, locale dependent)
dtOtp = CDate(sOtp)
WScript.Echo 2, TypeName(dtOtp), dtOtp, "(german locale, dmy)"

' CDate (risky, monthname, locale dependent)
dtOtp = CDate(Join(Array(aParts(1), aParts(2), aParts(3))))
WScript.Echo 3, TypeName(dtOtp), dtOtp, "(german locale, dmy)"
```

output:

```
cscript 48193001.vbs
String 10/1/2018
1 Date 10.01.2018 (german locale, dmy)
2 Date 10.01.2018 (german locale, dmy)
3 Date 10.01.2018 (german locale, dmy)
```