# Cannot convert my variables to CDate or Serial Date, getting Mismatch error

Tags: vbscript

I've ready numerous posts here about the mismatch error but every format I try I still get the same error.

```
Dim calendarDate, sDate, sFinal

calendarDate = "Sun Apr 05 00:00:00 CDT 2020"
sYear = Right(calendarDate, 4)
sDay = Mid(calendarDate,9,2)
sMonth = Mid(calendarDate,5,3)

If sMonth = "Apr" Then sMonth = "04" Else sMonth = sMonth
End if

sDate = sYear & "-" & sMonth & "-" & sDay


sFinal = CDate(sDate)
```

I get the type mismatch CDate error but the format should work? I have also tried MM/DD/YYYY.

And I have tried sFinal = DateSerial(sYear,sMonth,SDay) also does not work. But if you don't use the variables...

sFinal = DateSerial("2020","04","05") this works. I don't understand why my SYear, SMonth, SDay would not work as they are the same numbers."

My **end goal** here is to subtract 14 days from the calendar date but i can't even get my variable into a date format to subtract it...so maybe there is something simpler I should be doing here?

Thank you all for any help you can give much appreciated! Long time reader, first time posting.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48243660/692942) for an explanation of why you get that error and how to fix it. Basically, you need to drop the `Sun` and `CDT` before parsing the date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to manipulate will be to use [`Split()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/0764e5w5(v=vs.84)) as each value separated by a Space (`Chr(32)`).

What you end up with is an array containing each element that made up the string split by the Space character (`Chr(32)`), so by concatenating values back together we can construct our date-time how [`CDate()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/2dt118h2(v=vs.84)) expects, excluding the first and sixth element which will be `Sun` and `CDT` respectively, as well as re-ordering the year in the constructed string that is passed to `CDate()`.

```vb
Dim input: input = "Sun Apr 05 00:00:00 CDT 2020"
Dim data: data = Split(input, Chr(32))
'Ignore first and sixth element in the array and build our date value
Dim output: output = CDate(data(1) & " " & data(2) & " " & data(5)) & " " & TimeValue(data(3))
Call Wscript.Echo(output)
```

Output:

```
05/04/2020 00:00:00
```

> **Note**: Result will be based on the user's regional settings as `CDate()` uses this while parsing a `Date` string.

---

#### Useful Linkss

- [UTC time stamp format - Split in parts a string containing the UTC time date (classic asp/vbscript)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48243660/692942) *(Example of parsing date string)*.

Comment: Thank you for the information, unfortunately i am still getting the mismatch error using this method.

Comment: @Kevin how are you getting a mismatch, I've just tested it based on the value in your question? Try my example code on its own does that error?

Comment: Nevermind!! I did not comment out my last work. This does work for me thank you so much!!!

Comment: Thank you! I just accepted it, sorry still new to this. I do not have enough reputation yet to upvote it apparently.

Comment: Hello again, still struggling with this for some reason. Your logic works if the text is in quotes like your input variable...but if I use my variable calendarDate from my source data, I continue to get the mismatch error. Any ideas? I can print out both strings and they return the exact same thing it does not make sense to me.

Comment: @Kevin my answer was based on the information you provided, unfortunately we can’t read minds. The likelihood will be the value from source data does not match what you assume is the output. Where does the source data come from a database, spreadsheet, text file etc.?

Comment: I figured this out thanks for reaching out again. The issue was due to the script looping to a blank record. Had to check the split(0) and see what it was outputting and make sure it was skipping the last record.

Comment: @Kevin you could capture that with a simple `If` statement checking if `Len(input & "") > 0`.

Comment: that is probably an easier method than what i was doing thanks! I appreciate everyone's feedback on this one.